# How do I calculate Private Residence Relief for a house I've sold where there was a loss, not a gain?

Tags: united-kingdom, real-estate, capital-gains-tax

This question is likely specific to UK rules.

I've sold a flat which I lived in for part of the time I owned it. I'm trying to fill out the Inland Revenue's 'report my Capital Gains Tax' [form](https://www.gov.uk/capital-gains-tax/report-and-pay-capital-gains-tax).

I've read the [rules on Private Residence Relief](https://www.gov.uk/tax-sell-home/let-out-part-of-home) and I think I understand how to calculate the proportion of the gain that applies to me (which normally apply to the amount of the gain I believe).

However, in my case, I only made a very small gross gain on my property, and in fact overall made a small net loss once accounting for purchase and sale costs as the form guides me.

Nevertheless, the form *still* asks for the *amount* of Private Residence Relief. What should I enter? If I made a loss, do I multiply the proportion of time I didn't live there by the loss, and enter that as a positive number? This appears to reduce the loss in the provisional calculation, which seems logically correct, but just need to check the loss is equivalent to the gain for the purposes of this calculation. Or do I enter '0'?

I realize that in any case I will pay £0 CGT here, so just trying to make sure the paperwork is correct and any losses are fully recorded.

Comment: I've seen a lot of comments on HMRC-related questions suggesting that HMRC can be very helpful if you phone them. So this might be something they can answer over the phone.

Comment: There may be a long wait, but in short: Yes.

Answer (score 0):

It's all £Nil and I think you don't need to complete that section unless you have gains to report or losses you wish to carry forward.